# Format[] and Power[]

Tags: formatting

Suppose I have a simple dot product function DP that I want to display nicely, I might use e.g.

`Format[DP[x,y],StandardForm]:= (x\[CenterDot]y)`

If x == y, then I'll have a different rule:

`Format[DP[x,x],StandardForm]:= x^2`

How can I have a rule that sets `DP[x,x]^n = x^(2n)`? I've tried

`Format[DP[x,x]^(n_.),StandardForm]:= x^(2n)` but I get hit with an error:

SetDelayed::write: Tag Power in MakeBoxes[(x^2)^n_.,StandardForm] is Protected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Format[DP[x_, y_], StandardForm] := (x·y)
Format[DP[x_, x_], StandardForm] := x^2

Unprotect[Power];
Format[DP[x_, x_]^(n_), StandardForm] := x^(2 n)
Protect[Power];

DP[a, b]
(* a·b *)

DP[a, a]
(* a^2 *)

DP[b, b]^6
(* b^12 *)
```

Comment: Your second example produces `(a\[CenterDot]a)` on my system (v13.2.1 on a Mac).  `Format[DP[x_, x_], StandardForm] := x^2` is also needed.

Comment: @BobHanlon, you're right, thanks! I had not properly cleaned the definitions from testing :)